After updating my go toolchain using linux homebrew, I am running into go lang compilation error
The error message that I see

compile: version "go1.21.5" does not match go tool version "go1.22.2"

There is no reference to go1.21.5 in my code base. But I have the following go binaries
$ /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/go version
go version go1.22.2 linux/amd64

$ /usr/local/go/bin/go version
go version go1.21.5 linux/amd64

Why is my package giving me this error, when I have no reference to go1.21.5 in my package, and how can I fix this error?
FWIW, my go env is
GO111MODULE=''
GOARCH='amd64'
GOBIN=''
GOCACHE='/home/senthilx/.cache/go-build'
GOENV='/home/senthilx/.config/go/env'
GOEXE=''
GOEXPERIMENT=''
GOFLAGS=''
GOHOSTARCH='amd64'
GOHOSTOS='linux'
GOINSECURE=''
GOMODCACHE='/home/senthilx/go/pkg/mod'
GONOPROXY=''
GONOSUMDB=''
GOOS='linux'
GOPATH='/home/senthilx/go'
GOPRIVATE=''
GOPROXY='direct'
GOROOT='/usr/local/go'
GOSUMDB='sum.golang.org'
GOTMPDIR=''
GOTOOLCHAIN='auto'
GOTOOLDIR='/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64'
GOVCS=''
GOVERSION='go1.22.2'
GCCGO='gccgo'
GOAMD64='v1'
AR='ar'
CC='cc'
CXX='c++'
CGO_ENABLED='1'
GOMOD='/home/senthilx/git/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/go.mod'
GOWORK=''
CGO_CFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_CPPFLAGS=''
CGO_CXXFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_FFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_LDFLAGS='-O2 -g'
PKG_CONFIG='pkg-config'
GOGCCFLAGS='-fPIC -m64 -pthread -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build702252297=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches'


Does this answer your question? compile: version "go1.9" does not match go tool version "go1.9.1". I believe you may need export GOROOT=”$(brew — prefix golang)/libexec” (but that's from a quick search as I've not used linuxbrew).
